# kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException at com.yaark.player.ServiceClass.onDestroy

Tags: android, android-studio, exception, service

Exception causing a crash on some devices. Mainly crash found on Samsung high-end device eg. a30, s10+

*Cause:*

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService (ActivityThread.java:4377)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900 (ActivityThread.java:269)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2047)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7860)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: 
at com.yaark.player.ServiceClass.onDestroy (ServiceClass.java:25)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopService (ActivityThread.java:4357)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900 (ActivityThread.java:269)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2047)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7860)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

*code:*

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(serviceRunnable)
        player.reset()
        listener = null
        myService = null
        unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver)
        super.onDestroy()  
}
```

Service is stopped by selfStop()

Comment: It seems the variable `player` is `lateinit` & is found uninitialised when `onDestroy()` is called.
Make sure to properly `initialise` it, either in `onStart` or `onCreate`. Also you can check if the variable is initialised & then call reset like: `if (this::player.isInitialized) player.reset() `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if (this::player.isInitialized)` `player.reset()`

OR

declare player as nullable and use `player?.reset()`
it will ensure null safety.